# How to mathematically describe this Graph Theory problem?

Tags: graph-theory

so I am try to work out how I can write the optimal solution to the proposed graph problem below (mathematically). The way I have proposed the problem may not be consistent with current graph theory literature.

Anyway, the problem I am trying to solve is; I wish to find the independent sets from layer 1 of the graph such that when the vertices in layer 1 are selected, they will remove themselves and their associated sub-graph. The selection of these independent sets needs to ensure that the remaining graph of layer 2 will have the minimal chromatic number. All independent sets shall also be disjoint.

In the example below, clearly the selection of vertices V1,V5,V7 as the independent set of layer 1 would remove sub-graphs 1-3, therefore reducing the chromatic number to 0 which would always be optimal.

[image: graph]